# Python Script to extrude faces on a plane?

Tags: python, scripting

I'm working on a blender project that could be more easily done via a python script. Unfortunately, I don't know much about python or scripting within Blender.

So I've got a plane that's loop-cut-and-and-slid into a 9x7 matrix of  square faces. I need to extrude these faces at different values that can be found on an excel spreadsheet.

I'd like to script this process to start from a face, extrude it the necessary amount (anywhere from 0 to 4.5), and then move onto the next face, extrude it the necessary amount, and on and on until all of the faces have been extruded.

Can anyone assist me with creating this script?